# Adobe Acrobat Saving Grayscale not CMYK or RBG

Tags: adobe-acrobat, grayscale

This is a new problem for me. Acrobat is saving grayscale removing all color info. It appears color in Acrobat but will go gray in Photoshop. Checked settings to make sure not grayscale.

Ideas please?

Comment: Did you check Photoshop color mode?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Tried that. Switched between cmyk and rgb just to try with no difference. It is missing color information when it goes from adobe save to photoshop.

Comment: A search on Web didn't show similar cases. Must be a setting in Acrobat Preferences or in Save As that causes this result. You should try to export the PDF (as Word document, HTML or image) to see if the problem persists...

Comment: Thank you. Where do I find a setting change for save as?

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat open the View menu, go to Tools and click on Print Production.

Click now on Convert Colors. In Convert Colors set Convert Command to Convert to Profile and in Conversion Profile choose Adobe RGB. Rendering Intent should be set to Use Document Intent. Click OK and click Yes on the following warning message.

If these settings don't solve your problem, try to [reset](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/reset-photoshop-preferences/) Photoshop preferences.